# CSS: parent has overflow-y but my absolute child wants to have negative left

Tags: css

How to make child "#mark" element to appears "-10px left" inside a div with "overflow-y:hidden " property

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yX9j8/

Tooking off the overflow-y makes visible the "mark" element -10px to left.

[image]

Comment: ok, fixed. but i guessed that the exemple and question title would be self explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by adding a padding to the scroll, using the background-color on the content instead (looks like that is what matters for you), then the absolute div can be visible on the padding, and will follow the scroll.

```
#scrollable{
    padding-left: 10px; /* padding goes here */
    /*background-color:#eee;*/
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative;
}
#content{
    background-color:#eee; /* background color goes here */
    height:1900px;
    width:100%;   
}
#mark{
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#aaa;
    left: 0;  /* the position of the absoute element */ 
}
```

​

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yX9j8/5/

Answer (score 1):

My instinct told me to set `overflow-x: visible`, but that did not resolve the issue. I took a look in the [WC3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x), and as I interpret it, this is not possible to achieve with `overflow`. This is what it says:

> The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’.

This would mean that the `overflow-x: visible` would be set to `auto` when combined with `overflow-y: scroll` and thus hide the overflow.